# Preventing onchange events from getting into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, onchange

I have two text fields, one represents a percentage and the second represents a corresponding amount. Now what I want is, when the percentage changes the amount should change and when the amount changes the percentage should change accordingly. I am using javascript.

In this case, if any of them changes an infinite loop will start.

What I would like is that when the amount changes, it should change the percentage accordingly and then the loop should stop. And when the percentage changes, it should change the amount accordingly and then the loop should stop. Is there any way for this? Maybe something like `stopPropagation` ?

Dummy JS Code:

Here `value` is one text box and `percentage` is another text box

```
function valueChng(){
    percentage.value = "" + someInteger;
}
function percentageChng(){
    value.value = "" + someInteger;
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: How does you handlers for change event look like? Ordinarily, setting value for field via JS doesn't fire "change" event, hence shouldn't cause infinite change event loop.

Comment: Could you post some code or a fiddle? The Solution to your Problem depends on how you change the content and on which event you are listening.

Comment: @WTK Added a dummy code.

Comment: @kanishk - Check out Simon response - as you can see from fiddle he provided - simply changing value of field by code doesn't fire "change" event. You have to do something wrong in other place in your code (like calling *valueChng* / *percentageChng* functions by hand multiple times).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I still don't see a problem here, as a change handler is not executed when the content is changed programmatically. I just implemented a simple fiddle to show how it is working without running into in infinite loop (using jquery for simplicity):
http://jsfiddle.net/aWuks/

Comment: Yeah you right they are not looping. So now I would like to ask why are they not looping? I mean when the value of the other text box changes, it should trigger its own onchange event?

Comment: According to the W3C, "the onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus". The element is not losing focus when its value is changed programmatically, to the event is not fired.

Comment: So there is no way we can automatically cause the second event to occur itself, all we can do is call the function associated with the second event in the end of the first event. Right?

Comment: At least in jQuery, you could of course also trigger the event by calling $('#percentage').change() or $('#absolut').change()

Comment: Thats true @Simon, and is a great rule for preventing event loops everywhere. So I have a lib that loops itself exactly because when something is done programatically, it fires the changes as if manually, entering the loop. Eliminate that and the problem is solved! tks

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head:

```
var changedFlag = false;

function valueChng(){
    if(changedFlag == true) {
      changedFlag = false;
      return;
    }

    percentage.value = "" + someInteger;
    changedFlag = true;
}
function percentageChng(){
    if(changedFlag == true) {
      changedFlag = false;
      return;
    }

    value.value = "" + someInteger;
    changedFlag = true;
}
```

This way second of two 'onchange' events will be always ignored.

Comment: Yeah this seems a good way. I guess `Return;` simply ends that function execution right? And one more thing, since I have 5 such pairs I will not need a different flag for each pair right?

Comment: Yes, `return` works as you described and yes, you should use different _flag_ variables for different contexts.

Comment: See Simons answer. We dont need this. :)